# Using a VO in actionscript between classes

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, getter-setter, value-objects

In my class, I built a Weather VO (Visual Object) and now need to use it for another class.
 How would I use it to modify the values of the text field in my second class? I attempted using getters and setters to no avail.

**First Page:**

```
vo=new WeatherVO();//Visual Object for the weather data
    vo.city = _xmlData.channel.ns1::location.@city+", "+_xmlData.channel.ns1::location.@region;//city, st
    vo.currentTemp = _xmlData.channel.item.ns1::condition.@temp;
    vo.currentCondition = _xmlData.channel.item.ns1::condition.@text;
    vo.currentCode = _xmlData.channel.item.ns1::condition.@code;
    vo.sunrise = _xmlData.channel.ns1::astronomy.@sunrise;
    vo.sunset = _xmlData.channel.ns1::astronomy.@sunset;
```

**Second page:**

```
    public function set vo(value:WeatherVO):void
    {
        _weather=value;
    }

    public function get vo():WeatherVO
    {
        return _weather;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your getters and setters should be methods of the `WeatherVO` class that aid in the modification and retrieval **of properties within that class**. With the limited code sample you have provided, my recommendation is to pass the weather data through your `WeatherVO` constructor like so.

```
public function WeatherVO(_city:String, _currentTemp:String, _currentCondition:String, _currentCode:String, _sunrisde:String, _sunset:String) {
    city = _city;
    currentTemp = _currentTemp;
    currentCondition = _currentCondition;
    currentCode = _currentCode;
    sunrise = _sunrise;
    sunset = _sunset;
}

//Here is an example getter and setter for the city value.
public function get City() {
    return city;
}

public function set City(_city:String) {
    city = _city;
}
```